# Custom Price reverts on Order Edit

Tags: magento-1.9

If I place an order via Admin and set a "Custom Price", when I go back to edit that order in the admin the price then reverts back to the normal price and doesn't keep the Custom Price that has been set.

I found this: http://www.fetchdesigns.com/blog/magento-custom-price-lost-on-order-edit/
But it doesn't seem to fix the problem for me, in Magento 1.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under
$item->setCustomPrice($orderItem->getPrice());
you should also add
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($orderItem->getPrice());
Otherwise it’s not working for me either…